# Eclipse does not save files before build

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, autosave

I use Eclipse 2021-09 on macOS 11.6. When I edit a file and press the `Run` button, it does not save the file before build.

In General --> Workspace --> Build I checked "Save automatically before manual build"

When I manually save the file before build, it works as expected.

Any idea what problem it could be?

Answer (score 2):

Run != Build. You want the first two options on the Launching preference page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I chose "Always" in "Save required dirty editors before launching", but still same result

Comment: Strange. Using which editor? Would it know that the file being edited affects what you're launching?

Comment: There is only one file. When I save it manually, it works fine

Comment: Right, and it's the Java Editor inside Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, and it *works* when I save the file manually

Answer (score 0):

After uninstallation and deletion of all related files, a new installation worked fine.